# Why in LINQ the Where clause gets executed after GroupBy?

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, lambda, group-by

In a C# application in .NET Core that manages an auditing process within a company, I have two datasets, `Expert` and `Employee` belonging to `_context`.

- `Employee` refers to all those people internal to the company, therefore
  they got a company identifier, `Cid`. In `Employee` there could be several records with the same `Cid` but the validity of the record is estabilished through the `StartDate` - `EndDate` interval.
- `Expert` might refer to both `Employee`(`Internal` flag set to `true`) and people external to the company, therefore not all the records in `Expert` have a `Cid`. Not every `Employee` is an `Expert`.

The dataset have are modeled as follows:

```
class Employee{
    public int Cid { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Surname { get; set;}
    public string Address { get; set;}
    public DateTime StartDate{ get; set;}
    public DateTime EndDate{ get; set;}
}

class Expert{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public bool Internal { get; set;}
    public int Cid { get; set;}
}
```

I would like to get a list with all the `Experts` and for those `Internal` I would like to get also the `Name`, `Surname` and `Address` with the highest `EndDate`.

The first step is a `left join` between `Expert` and `Employee`:

```
var experts = from exp in _context.Expert
              join emp in _context.Employee
              on exp.Cid equals emp.Cid into experts
              from expertsDetail in experts.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new 
              {
                  emp.Cid,
                  emp.Name,
                  emp.Surname,
                  emp.Address,
                  emp.StartDate,
                  emp.EndDate,
                  exp.Internal
              };
```

Then I filter just those records that are `Internal` and then group by `Cid`. Then, within any grouping, I find the maximum date in order to used to select the correct `Internal` record within `experts`

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> expertsByCid = experts.Where(e => e.Internal)
                                                   .GroupBy(e => e.Cid)
                                                   .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Max(t => t.EndDate));

experts.Where(e => e.Internal ? e.EndDate == expertsByCid[e.Cid] : true);
```

The first instruction from the code above throws a `NullReferenceException`.
The same applies for this one:

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> expertsByCid = (from expert in (from expert in experts where expert.Internal select expert)
group expert by expert.Cid).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Max(t => t.EndDate));
```

Instead if I use this one:

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> expertsByCid = experts.Where(e => e.Internal)
                                                   .ToList()
                                                   .GroupBy(e => e.Cid)
                                                   .ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Max(t => t.EndDate));
```

the code gets executed without issues and I get the expected result. Probably in the first version, when `LINQ` translates the query to `SQL`, the `WHERE` clause is executed after the `GROUPBY`and therefore it groups also records that are not `Internal`, where the `Cid` is `null`.

I tried to check the executed SQL by turning on the proper log level (I use .NET Core) but since it throws an exception it does not show the created query.

This explanation though seems a bit illogical, has anybody else a better one?

Comment: Look at the actual generated SQL and see what it does, rather than just guessing what it might be.

Comment: LINQPad is a good tool for looking at generated SQL.

Comment: Your `experts` definition is incomplete.

Comment: @NetMage thanks for LinqPad. Why is the definition incomplete? What is it missing?

Comment: @Servy, I didn’t look at it because it seems rather wrong that a where gets executed after a group by, so it shouldn’t happen in the first place

Comment: @CiccioMiami Okay, so you didn't think to do it before.  Now that you know you should look, what was the generated SQL?

Comment: @Servy, I activated the log in the application (.NET Core) and unfortunately, since it throws the exception, it does not display the executed SQL. I also tried to split the Where and GroupBy functions from the ToDictionary with no success. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure the null ref exception isn't being thrown due to your left join returning a null `expertsDetail`?

Comment: @CoryNelson, yes I am sure, if you see the piece of code that works I execute the query by chaining ToList() after the Where() and that expressione does not give me any issue. The issue is that it tries to GroupBy when the Cid is null (Internal == false)

Comment: In C#, there must be a `select` included in a LINQ Query. You can't use `experts` as a variable and as the range variable in the query. The statement doesn't end in a `;`. It won't compile.